# Problem in showing data in a table for single object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, angular7

I have a function in angular as:

```
 memberDtos=[];

    getDataOfDtoCache(cacheData:any,nameOfCache:String){
        console.log(nameOfCache);
        this.hasTableClicked=true;
           this.memberDtos.push(cacheData);
            this.tableName=nameOfCache;
         console.log(this.memberDtos);
      }
```

While doing  console.log(this.memberDtos); I am getting a single Object as:

```
GBIM: false
GBI: false
NCHL_T: false
NCHLST: false
NIB_Q: false
NIBL_S: false
P_RQ: false
PES: false
SQ: false
SBL_RES: false
STLME_REQ: false
STL_IME_RES: false
STLIBL_REQ: false
SN_RES: false
STRVU_REQ: false
SU_RES: false
S_REQ: false
STL_RES: false
```

I want this single object to come in table as:

[image]

But in html part I used KendoUI as:

```
   <kendo-grid 
              [kendoGridBinding]="memberDtos" 

              [resizable]="true"
              [filterable]="true"
              [groupable]="true"
              [sortable]="true"
              [pageable]="{
                buttonCount:4,
                pageSizes:[5,10,15]
                }"
              [pageSize]="5"
              *ngIf="hasTableClicked && tableName=='Member DTO'"   >

                  <kendo-grid-column field="memberId" title="Bo Id" width="70">
                  </kendo-grid-column>
                  <kendo-grid-column field="memberCode" title="Client Dealer Id" width="100s">
                  </kendo-grid-column>

              </kendo-grid>
```

But in my UI I got the whole data at single row as:

[image]

It is just showing me one single row.I want entire data to come in different rows.Can i get it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kendoGridBinding` accepts data as an (iterable) array of objects. You need to transform your data into array of `key: value` objects to be able to display the values in different columns as on your image.

Here's [working JSFiddle example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1tvvp?file=app/app.component.ts) of what it should look like

Traverse the input data with `for in` loop and push the data into memberDtos array as `{ key: value }`